# How does the following Django code work?

Tags: python, django, django-forms, django-views

I am trying to understand the following code better. It's working, but I just don't fully understand several elements (questions below):

```
from django.shortcuts import render_to_response
from mywiki.wiki.models import Page
from django.http import HttpResponseRedirect
from django import forms
import markdown

class SearchForm(forms.Form):
    text = forms.CharField(label='Enter search term')

def search_page(request):
    if request.method =='POST':
        f = SearchForm(request.POST)
        if not f.is_valid():
            return render_to_response('search.html', {'form':f})
        else:
            pages = Page.objects.filter(name__contains = f.cleaned_data['text'])
            return render_to_response('search.html', {'form':f, 'pages':pages})
    f = SearchForm()
    return render_to_response('search.html', {'form':f})

specialPages = {'SearchPage':search_page}

def view_page(request, page_name):
    if page_name in specialPages:
        return specialPages[page_name](request)
    try:
        page = Page.objects.get(pk=page_name)
    except Page.DoesNotExist:
        return render_to_response('create.html', {'page_name':page_name})

    content = page.content    
    return render_to_response('view.html', {'page_name':page_name, 'content':markdown.markdown(content)})
```

1. Why do we need to specify that the `request.method` has to be `POST` - wouldn't clicking an HTML button implicitly signal an intent to change/affect something? Or `POST` is only appropriate when the action affects the database?
2. How does the line `pages = Page.objects.filter(name__contains = f.cleaned_data['text'])` work? It takes the model `Page(models.Model)`, but what do the 'objects' and 'filter' methods do in this case?
3. In the `view_page`, why do we need to add `(request)` in `return specialPages[page_name](request)`

Thanks!

Comment: You should really go through the [Django Tutorial](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/intro/tutorial01/) first. If you had, you should know all of these answers. It doesnt take very long and you might even enjoy it.

Comment: https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/forms/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. The `POST` test is used as a differentiator.

   When the view is called with `GET`, the form is rendered. The form specifies that it needs to be submitted with using `POST`, so the code assumes that a `POST` request signals the form is submitted.
2. The `objects` attribute triggers the actual database query. By adding the `.filter()` call you specify a more specific database query, one where the `name` attribute contains the value of `f.cleaned_data['text']`. The result is a set of database results that match that query.
3. the `specialPages` dictionary values are themselves views, and for these to work, you call them with the `request` parameter. Just like the `view_page` view callable itself.